# Uwamp - Php 5++ run well but stop and not working after change to Php 7

Tags: uwamp

Uwamp Version: 3.1.0
Installation : USB Drive

---

I just download Uwamp 3.1.0 today and everything run well but apache will stop if I switch to php 7. It happen only if I switch to php 7, and when I switch it back to php 5, apache work fine..

**The error I get from Uwamp:**

httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 166 of G:/uwamp/bin/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load G:/uwamp/bin/php/php-7.0.3/php7apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.

**In httpd.config line 166**

LoadModule php7_module "G:/uwamp/bin/php/php-7.1.0-Win32-VC14-x86/php7apache2_4.dll"

---

I found the httpd error asked by someone in this forum but got no answer and the different is the version of Uwamp and Php.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

ManuDevil, thank you for the answer..

Yup **Visual C++ Redistributable 2015** is needed to run php 7.

***Before use UwAmp you must install Visual C++ Redistributable x86 version vc_redist.x86.exe. This is a PHP requirement.***

For **PHP older** version you need :  Visual C++ Redistributable 2005

For **PHP 5.3** you need : Visual C++ Redistributable 2008

For **PHP 5.4+** you need : Visual C++ Redistributable 2012

For **PHP 7.x+** you need : Visual C++ Redistributable 2015

Answer (score 1):

As written on http://www.uwamp.com/fr/?page=download :

For PHP 7.x+ you need : [Download VC14 2015 vc_redist.x86.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

You can install multiple versions of **Redistributable for Visual Studio** and you can install both version x86 and x64. **UwAmp use x86 version** to keep compatibility with older PHP version.